# How to fetch file from url without knowing its extension in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

In my app I have an api that returns back a file. However, I don't know the extension of the file in advance.

How can I download that file in React-Native(0.59.8)?

Comment: do you know what type of response it is? like application/octet-stream, blob..?

Comment: seems like an oversight that you cant get the file name. maybe you should be returning file types and paths and sizes etc. If you wrote the api then you should be able to add a type.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below given code.

```
  import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';
  download = async(path) =>{
          console.log('URL', path);

          var date      = new Date();
          var url       =  path;
          var ext       = this.extention(path);
          ext = "."+ext[0];
          const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob
          let PictureDir = fs.dirs.PictureDir
          let options = {
            fileCache: true,
            addAndroidDownloads : {
              useDownloadManager : true,
              notification : true,
              path:  PictureDir + "/MyFile_"+Math.floor(date.getTime() + date.getSeconds() / 2)+ext,
              description : 'File'
            }
          }
          config(options).fetch('GET', url).then((res) => {
         Alert.alert("Success Downloaded");

    });
        }
      extention(filename){
          return (/[.]/.exec(filename)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(filename) : undefined;
        }
```